# Internal Testing only Uninstall Button showing after Install an App from Google Play Store

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-games, unreal-engine4

I've made a game app with UE4 for google play store and I uploaded it for internal testing. The first version was ok I uploaded it and the testers could download it and open but then they got an error message while opening the app about keystore obb file missing and I fixed that. But now when they download the game and install it, the open button disappears and it has only uninstall option available also a message pops up saying "thank you for trying the app before it's released".

So I am wondering have I done something wrong? Or does the app need more time to sync with google play store, it's been 12-13 hours since I uploaded. Also, does anyone know how long you have to wait for internal testing new release update to be active? Can't find a clear answer anywhere.

PS: I cleared cache but still got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

x00678,

I've met the same problem; Check out your AndroidManifest.xml. Under the Application -> Activity section should be block `<intent-filter>`. It means a kind of intent that the app receives outside.
So, it should be like that:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

If you have additional lines inside of this block, just put it to another  if you are not 100% sure these lines should be in the same block with main action - launcher.
Besides I am sure that including `<data android:scheme>` to launcher `<intent-filter>` block breaks the launcher.

Comment: That is already in the manifest the UE4 creates, but it Android studio it wont execute it. So basically the app after bundling it doesn't work. I found another solution, I stopped packing the whole thing in the APK an left the OBB file separate. So I am uploading the APK and then I add an expansion file and it's working, but don't know what will happen when google accepts bundles only for upload.

Thanks for the replay